# bootstrap jquery tree should expand automatically to desired location

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have the bootstrap jQuery tree and i want to expand tree to desired node, when the page is loaded.

Is there any way to expand the tree to desired location at start of page loading.

Here is the code

```
<script>
$('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function(){
$(this).parent().find(".glyphicon-plus").removeClass("glyphicon-plus").addClass("glyphicon-minus");
}).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function(){
$(this).parent().find(".glyphicon-minus").removeClass("glyphicon-minus").addClass("glyphicon-plus");
});
</script>
```

Comment: Could you link to the jQuery tree? I'll need to look at the plugin's source code to try and help.

Comment: here is the code:


<script>
$('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function(){
$(this).parent().find(".glyphicon-plus").removeClass("glyphicon-plus").addClass("glyphicon-minus");
}).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function(){
$(this).parent().find(".glyphicon-minus").removeClass("glyphicon-minus").addClass("glyphicon-plus");
});
</script>

Comment: Without seeing mode code it is difficult to troubleshoot this, as a blind guess I would assume that the tree is using bootstrap's collapse functionality. If so, then you can add the class `in` to any node you would want expanded on load. Again, you need to post more code so we can try to identify the issue.

Comment: I still do not know which plugin you are using or where your structure is from. Your script for an accordion, not a tree. This is a tree: [jsTree](http://www.jstree.com/)